# Is there a word for the coronation of a king who won his crown by reunifying the country, but is not the heir apparent?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

After sacking the capital of a country, and seeing that nation fall, there is no longer a central authority. A leader/lord/nobleman establishes himself as the ruler and starts to subjugate the enemy's incursion. After the enemy is pushed back, the ”leader” is enthroned.

Does this process count as a coronation or can someone be crowned even though they are not the [heir apparent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heir%20apparent#:%7E:text=1%20%3A%20an%20heir%20whose%20right,appears%20certain%20under%20existing%20circumstances)? Is using the term "be crowned" proper, or there is a specific word to describe this process of becoming king?

Comment: This is a question better suited to History.SE apart from asking if there is a word for a "commoner" who is crowned, the rest is focused on the legitimacy of someone outside the royal family  nucleus being crowned.  It has little to do with language as such.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network; stipulative definitions about legitimacy of conferring of titles / positions is more a political than a linguistic question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA This isn't a good fit for History SE because it's not about real history.

Comment: I don't know but I think it could fit, @KillingTime, for example asking for actual episodes in history when a commoner or nobleman ascended to the throne and whether a coronation ceremony was still celebrated. It might be closed for lack of research.

Comment: Maybe it belongs on World building?

Answer (score 2):

The word *coronation* usually denotes a formal ceremony at which a crown (real or metaphorical) is placed on the head of the new monarch.  For example, Chambers provides the definition:

> the ceremony of crowning

As to the process of becoming the monarch, well, coronation may or may not be essential.  You describe a situation where someone has *siezed the crown* by force and become *de facto* king.  In some places and at some times that would have been entirely sufficient.  However, history will provide numerous examples of cases of a *usurper* undergoing *coronation* to legitimise their siezure of power, or at least to put a gloss of legitimacy on it.

In some monarchies the reign of one monarch begins immediately upon the death of the reigning monarch.  For uncontested transfers of power this depends on the line of inheritance having been settled beforehand.  The British monarchy provides a current example of this.  The coronation of a new British sovereign is a formality, the line is established by *Acts of Settlement*.

In other monarchies there may be an *interregnum* between the death of one monarch and the accession to the throne of the next.  The would-be monarch may have to demonstrate their right to ascend the throne, or that their right is stronger than other claimants.  Being the first-born male son of the recently deceased monarch may not be sufficient. In these cases the new reign may only begin when the crown is placed on the head of the successor.

So, to answer your question .... no, siezing the crown by force is not a form of *coronation* though it may be very effective.

Comment: The OP says, “After the enemy is pushed back, he was enthroned.” That doesn’t sound like usurping the throne.

Comment: @Lawrence ... history is written by the winners, and royal families are never going to admit that they acquired the throne by violence :-)

Answer (score 0):

> After the enemy is pushed back, he was enthroned. Does this process count as a coronation?

Yes. If you go through a coronation, (the formal and legitimate placing of the crown on the head of the to-be monarch) then you have been enthroned (formally, and rightfully, put upon the throne), i.e. recognised as monarch.

> Is using the <s>term</s> passive verb "be crowned" proper?

Yes

> or there is a specific word to describe this process of becoming the king?

No, not really. Whether you accede to the title on the death of a monarch, or you take the title on monarch by force of arms, or by common consent, then your coronation/enthronement, etc. is the same. It is the act of formally installing someone as monarch.

Answer (score 0):

Coronation (crowning) is the ceremony by which the new monarch is formally recognised as such. That's **all** that can be said on the matter, so far as the language is concerned.

In order to decide whether the term can be applied to a specific event, one needs to know whether the ceremony is genuine (rather than, say, a scene in a play), and whether the person undergoing it is the genuine monarch (rather than, say, an actor playing the role of the monarch, or an obvious usurper, or, perhaps, somebody whose claim to power is limited in some way). Knowing some of these things requires much more than the knowing the meanings of the relevant words: it may involve the knowledge of the laws and traditions of the country in question and/or of the strengths of different social forces in it. All that is outside the scope of this site.

In the particular hypothetical scenario that the OP outlines, whether one will use the term *coronation* may also depend on the perspective from which one is speaking. For example, if there still are some supporters of the old regime around, chances are that they will regard the new ruler as an usurper, and refuse to use this term for the ceremony, even if it is widely used by others. Also, many people may be hesitant to use that term at first, if it appears uncertain whether the new ruler will be successful in establishing his rule in the long run, but may then later start using it in retrospect, if his rule is eventually accepted by everyone.